# Como mapear visualmente um app Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

tudo bom?

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta que desenha as rotas de um app?

Queria algo como:

- Telas do App com a rota e os controllers.

O meu projeto está tão grande, que ando precisando de um mapa... será que existe? Ou devo fazer manualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei algo no Visual Studio:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AngularDoc.angulardoc-vscode

Mas não pode na versão community.

Vou ter que fazer manualmente mesmo.... :(